# Reading Monetary Amount from application.yml Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to load a monetary amount from application.yml that has Currency and Amount like:

```
financeAmt:
        value: 10000
        currency: EUR
```

I want to use java Money API(`javax.money`) or any of its implementation e.g `org.javamoney.moneta.Money`

But Spring boot is not able to load the "financeAmt" with @ConfigurationProperties
it is setting it is as null.

It works fine if i create a custom class with the vale and currency properties.

Any help how can load this money values without creating custom class and using java money api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Boot does not know how to convert a `String` to `org.javamoney.moneta.Money`. If you are not tied to the format you could provide a `@ConfigurationPropertiesBinding` and use a config setting like:

```yaml
financeAmt:
  value: EUR 10000
```

```java
import org.javamoney.moneta.Money;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBinding;
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("finance-amt")
public class FinanceAmtConfig {
    private Money value;

    public Money getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Money value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

@Component
@ConfigurationPropertiesBinding
class MoneyConverter implements Converter<String, Money> {
    @Override
    public Money convert(String source) {
        // Needs some error handling....
        return Money.parse(source);
    }
}
```

Or if you are tied to the config format you could just read the primitive values e.g. a `String` and a `BigDecimal` and build the `Money` instance explicitly.

Comment: Thanks @Andreas.
Below configuration worked:
financeAmt:
  value: EUR 10000
We dont need the converter, Spring is able to convert it into Money object without it.